# Artificially creating memory usage in Python

Tags: python, performance, testing, memory

I'm trying to create a pure memory intensive script in Python for testing purposes but every script that I try also increases my cpu. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509322/how-to-implement-a-memory-intensive-python-script-for-test) and I also tried, among others:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

l1 = [17]*900
l2=[]

j=0
while j<9000:
    l2=l1
    j=j+1
print "Finished in ", datetime.now() - startTime
```

in order to copy an array to another array but once again I had cpu variations as well.

**UPDATED**
So, how can I cause a standard cpu utilization (100% usage in one core), 45% of memory utilization and after a couple of minutes an increase of memory utilization to 90%?

Comment: If the memory is not used (i.e. CPU), it will likely not be in RAM...

Comment: You can certainly allocate memory and not use it, but that's not very helpful for performance testing, because unused memory gets swapped out. If it's not even written to once, then it's purely virtual memory being allocated, not even physical.

Comment: ...anyhow, if your goal is to minimize CPU resource utilization, Python isn't the right tool for this particular task -- however efficient you make your Python script for the purpose, one will be able to do significantly better in C.

Comment: Just do `x = range(10**9)`? Short CPU-spike, lasting high memory-usage.

Comment: If your python script is single threaded, it's not going to incur more than 100% cpu.

Comment: So, how can I create a stable 40% memory usage with 100% cpu utilization in one core for two minutes and then an increase to 90% of memory usage with the same cpu utilization? Thank you @rrauenza

Comment: What is your definition of usage?  What is your actual goal?  You want to allocate memory and then spin the CPU on a calculation?  Do you want to be reading that memory?  Writing to it?   Why are you allocating it?  Are you creating an oppositional load to stress another app out?  Are you testing the hardware?

Comment: As you said in your answer I want to keep adding data to a list in order to increase memory utilization. What I want is to keep this utilization to a standard percentage for a while (40% or 50%) and after of few minutes to double this percentage.

Comment: btw, if you're doing this to simulate loads for monitoring purposes, that's very different than for measuring/benchmarking purposes.  It is helpful to know which you're modeling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of misconceptions that I'll try to address.

- You have to use CPU to use memory.  There's no other way.
- Your copy of a list is only assigning a pointer.  You're not moving memory.

If you want to increase memory utilization, you need to keep adding data to your list:

```
l = []
for i in range(0, 1024*1024):
    l.append("*" * 1024)
```

Or using something similar to your method,

```
l = [17] * 1024

for i in range(0, 16):
   l = l + l  # doubles the list each time.
```

That will allocate the memory.  If you want to measure access to it in isolation, you'll want to loop over `l` modifying the values or summing them.

```
sum(l)
```

or

```
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    l[i] += 1
```

In the end, your benchmark is going to be very simplistic (like doesn't address multiple cores accessing memory simultaneously, doesn't take into account processor caches, lookahead, random vs serial access, etc.)  Using Python is also not optimal because you are not in full control of the memory allocation and garbage collection.

Proper memory benchmarking is a deep subject...

Edit:

This is what you are asking for, more or less:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

memory1 = "*" * 1024**3

start = datetime.now()

j = 0

while (datetime.now() - start) < timedelta(minutes=1):
    j += 1

memory2 = "*" * 1024**3

while (datetime.now() - start) < timedelta(minutes=2):
    j += 1
```

You can adjust `memory1` and `memory2` to get your 40% and 90% depending on your actual system size.  The program *will* need to use the CPU while it allocates the string.  It first has to request the memory from the kernel, but then has to fill it in with `'*'`, otherwise the memory will only be virtual.  If you were writing this in C, you could just touch one byte in each 4k page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've updated my question. Your script increases both cpu and memory util.

Comment: Thank you @rrauenza You can change the second timedelta to 2 minutes in order to have the double memory utilization for the same time. Thank you again!!!